# Android Emulator is taking too much specs

Tags: android, memory, android-emulator, low-memory

My android emulator is using up too much memory, cpu, and disk. It also lags alot. My computer is a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 2in1 with a core i7 chip. It has 7.79gb ram usable.

I have browsed the web and looked at different solutions, but none of them work. I have even tried editing my Virtual Device and lowered all the required specs such as ram, vm heap, internal storage and other stuff. For additional information, I have debugged on a physical device and it works, but I don't think it is convenient to use a real phone each time, specially when I'm in the testing face of my project. Can someone please tell me how I can get a working emulator that works decently, but at the same time doesn't make my computer sound like a plane?

AVD :

Android Virtual Device Advanced Settings

Task Manager :

[TaskManagerDuringEmulatorAndBasicActivities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yOQ1.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what that means.